# C# foreach looping and matching. Is there a faster way to do this?

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach

I need to match values from one list to another. 
Both are list. Both have hundreds of thousands of records. 
Hoping someone can show me a way to make this a little quicker as it's taking quite long to match.

```
foreach (var item in availabilityItems)
{
    foreach (var page in from page in pricePageList
        where item.Number == page.VendorItemNo
        where item.StartDate == page.SubSeasonStartDate
        where item.EndDate == page.SubSeasonEndDate
        select page)
    {
        item.VendorItemNo = page.VendorItemNo;
        item.PricePageNo = page.PricePageNo;
        item.NaItemNo = page.ItemNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say records, where are you getting the records from? Is it a database?

Comment: AvailabilityItems is data from a csv and PricePageList is data from a SQL query. "Records" might not be the correct term though. Rows maybe? EDIT: I noticed you use Nav. I use the term records as I am also a C/AL dev.

Comment: Definitely sorting the data can make a HUGE difference here, so let's start with that: how is the data sorted? For the SQL, do you have the ability to change the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: I don't consider C/AL a language worth learning, it enrages me regularly, it's just a necessary evil :)

Comment: IMHO dump the csv data into a table, maybe even streaming the data directly via bulk insert. Are `item` and `page` the same type? Or should the item table join to the price table, with no real FK so you can trivially truncate / replace prices.

Answer (score 1):

If it can fit all in memory, you can use `Dictionary` to store the items for fast lookup. Depending on your database, this will reduce load on your db, eliminating the need for an index and sort at the db side, especially if you have to run this process frequently.

The code may be slightly easier to understand, although the other answer with reading two sorted lists is clever, it may require more complex code and also forces the db to do an order by, using up an index and additional IO.

Obviously if you have more than say 10 million records this starts to break down, but should be fine within that range of records.

```cs
Dictionary<string, PageItem> lookup = new Dictionary<string, PageItem>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Example bulk-load

```cs
foreach (var item in pricePageList)
{
    lookup[item.VendorItemNo + "|" + item.SubSeasonStartDate + "|" + item.SubSeasonEndDate] = item;
}
```

Example search:

```cs
foreach (var item in availabilityItems)
{
    string key = item.Number + "|" + item.SubSeasonStartDate + "|" + item.SubSeasonEndDate;
    if (lookup.TryGetValue(key, out PageItem match))
    {
        item.Number = match.VendorItemNo;
        item.PricePageNo = match.PricePageNo;
        item.NaItemNo = match.ItemNo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple algorithm which prevents multiple list scans.

**If both lists are sorted** on `Number/VendorItemNo`, you could use 2 index variables to scan top down and compare the `Number` to the `VendorItemNo`. If the `left` is bigger, increase the index of the `right`. Else if the `right` is higher, increase the index of the left. If they are equal, you got a match and increase both indices. The whole idea behind this is you only scan **once** through each list. It can be use on multiple lists also.

For example two lists sorted on id.

Use an index to scan them:

```
1234 <-    1233 <-
1236       1234
1237       1235
1238       1238
```

Compare them, left is higher than right, increase right.

---

```
1234 <-    1233
1236       1234 <-
1237       1235
1238       1238
```

We got a match. (ofcourse you have some extra criteria to check..) increase both

---

```
1234       1233
1236 <-    1234
1237       1235 <-
1238       1238
```

The left is higher, increase right

---

```
1234       1233
1236 <-    1234
1237       1235
1238       1238 <-
```

Now the right is higer, so increase left

---

```
1234       1233
1236       1234
1237 <-    1235
1238       1238 <-
```

Right is still higher, increase the left again.

---

```
1234       1233
1236       1234
1237       1235
1238 <-    1238 <-
```

We got a match... So only 1234 and 1238 are matching.

If one exceeds the count of the list, you're done.

Comment: This is commonly called a `merge join` and unfortunately there is nothing in LINQ yet for this

Comment: Not yet, but you can certainly walk the enumerators yourself to implement algorithm for your specific data.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you, I had this idea many years ago when merging 16 midi channels with events to 1 single channel. Great it is also a know algorithm.. TIL: Merge join.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `pricePageList` contains unique elements regarding the combination of the three fields, you could construct a [`Dictionary<TKey, Page>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) containing the pages, using as key a [`ValueTuple<int, DateTime, DateTime>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples). This type is comparable out of the box, so you won't have to supply a custom [`IEqualityComparer<TKey>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1).

```
var pricePageDictionary = pricePageList
    .ToDictionary(p => (p.VendorItemNo, p.SubSeasonStartDate, p.SubSeasonEndDate));

foreach (var item in availabilityItems)
{
    var key = (item.Number, item.StartDate, item.EndDate);
    if (pricePageDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var page))
    {
        item.VendorItemNo = page.VendorItemNo;
        item.PricePageNo = page.PricePageNo;
        item.NaItemNo = page.ItemNo;
    }
}
```

This should be blazingly fast, compared to the nested loop approach, because searching in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a O(1) operation.

Comment: I tried using this but I am getting a duplicate value error. It's hard to tell manually if there's duplicate data in this many records but can I add an if statement for whether the key already exists?

Comment: @NathanielDawg since the `pricePageList` has not unique values, creating a dictionary with the `ToDictionary` operator will fail. You can either create the dictionary manually, by enumerating the `pricePageList` and filling the dictionary using its `set` indexer instead of the `Add` method (preserving the last of the duplicates), or use the `ToLookup` operator that preserves all duplicates (each key can have multiple values). But you should first ask yourself what do you want to do with those cases. For each key, which one of the duplicate pages should update the matched item(s)?